# Mapbox iOS double tap handling

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox iOS SDK, making the next layout: mapView and two buttons ("zoom in" and "zoom out"). 
I can't figure out how to correctly handle double tap on buttons. 
Double tap on "zoom out" button zooms me in - as far as I understand, Mapbox's mapView intercept and handle my double tap.

I've tried the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
    let doubleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap))
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    zoomOutButton.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTap)

    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSingleTap))
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTap.require(toFail: doubleTap)
    zoomOutButton.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
```

and handlers (just to see it works):

```
func handleSingleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("single")
}

func handleDoubleTap(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("double")
}
```

It doesn't work. How can I handle double tap on "zoom out" button to zoom out twice?